# ADF data flow very slow

Tags: azure

On Azure Data Factory, I created a very simple data flow, source: blob tsv, sink: SQL DB table. 
It ran very slowly, 6mins for ~500 records.
Can anyone recommend how to troubleshoot this performance problems?
(Region: Australia East)

Answer (score -1):

I see similar results today. US West region. 1 csv file (33 rows x 6 columns) mapped to a single Azure SQL table. Taking in excess of 5 minutes to complete.

Comment: This is not an answer to @handitri question. It should be a comment, confirming that you see the same problem occurring.